# Postman save a byte array response into a file

Tags: xml, web-services, postman

I tried to test a web service with Postman, the response is OK, but an element in XML response is a byte array that I need save into a csv file.

I tried to use the option "Save and Download", but it saves the XML response in an XML file, but not the byte array into the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:runResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://editor.gtdw.xxx.com">
            <runReturn xsi:type="soapenc:base64Binary" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

                <-- byte[] is here!--> 

            </runReturn>
        </ns1:runResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

is this possible?

I can save the file with a program in java and works fine.

Comment: I don't think Postman has the option to do it. You can use the newman wrapper along with xml libraries to call the service, parse the response and log byte code.

Comment: I try with newman, and works, the problem is that it is for a non-expert user. Thanks for the help.